# Tableau running count reset

Tags: time-series, reset, tableau-api, restart

I have a list of sporting matches by time with result and margin. I want Tableau to keep a running count of number of matches since the last x (say, since the last draw - where margin = 0).

This will mean that on every record, the running count will increase by one unless that match is a draw, in which case it will drop back to zero.

I have not found a method of achieving this. The only way I can see to restart counts is via dates (e.g. a new year).

---

As an aside, I can easily achieve this by creating a running count tally OUTSIDE of Tableau.

The interesting thing is that Tableau then doesn't quite deal with this well with more than one result on the same day.

For example, if the structure is:

```
GameID   Date        Margin    Running count
...
48       01-01-15    54        122
49       08-01-15    12        123
50       08-01-15    0         124
51       08-01-15    17        0
52       08-01-15    23        1
53       15-01-15    9         2
...
```

Then when trying to plot running count against date, Tableau rearranges the data to show:

```
GameID   Date        Margin    Running count
...
48       01-01-15    54        122
51       08-01-15    17        0
52       08-01-15    23        1
49       08-01-15    12        123
50       08-01-15    0         124
53       15-01-15    9         2
...
```

I assume it is doing this because by default it sorts the running count data in ascending order when dates are identical.

Comment: Do you want Tableau to display a mark for each game? Or one mark for each day? The features that could be used to address this are table calculations and/or LOD calculations.

Comment: Each game if I can, but even when creating a count outside of Tableau (the second example above), Tableau rearranges the order of the games.